# Cannot use Composer 1.6.3 version of composer with fabric 1.1, v0.19 or higher is required

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm running the setup of application but while running it throwing below error.

```
./createPeerAdminCard.sh
Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'createPeerAdminCard.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv11
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)
```

> Cannot use Composer 1.6.3 2018-01-31 16:28:17 version of composer with fabric 1.1, v0.19 or higher is required

Comment: already tried ..... npm install -g composer-cli@0.19.0

Comment: I have the same problem and I have also tried with "npm install -g composer-cli@0.19.0 ". Although that command finish successfully, the issue was not solved yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
npm install -g composer-cli@0.19.9
```

this  worked for me.