# I get an error when using composer with fabic 1.2

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am currently trying to work through this tutorial [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-blockchain-network-using-hyperledger-fabric-and-composer-e06644ff801d)
When I try and run the createPeerAdminCard.sh script, i get the error `Cannot use Composer version 1.8.3 2019-01-30 08:31:33 version of composer with fabric 1.2, v0.20 or higher is required`

I have looked and it seems composer version 1.8.3 is the latest release, I just upgraded from 1.6.x and was getting the same error with that version of composer.

I have checked all of the prerequisites for installing composer here and I seem to have all the right versions ([Prerequisites](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html))

A similar post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50519979/cannot-use-composer-1-6-3-version-of-composer-with-fabric-1-1-v0-19-or-higher-i/51100717) but running the suggested `npm install -g composer-cli@0.x.x` did not seem to fix the issue.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use composer v0.20. I hope that will solve your issue.Hope it help.